# Display the sub-field of a Mongodb collection document

Tags: mongodb

I have to get list the matching documents from a MongoDB collection that has sub documents fields with array.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eea547c03c38e5a985ef32d"),
    "moduleId" : 1,
    "regionId" : 3,
    "country" : "null",
    "targetgroup" : {
        "mandate" : "COMPULSARY",
        "groups" : [1,2,4,7,10,12,13]
    },
    "level" : 2
}
```

and my query to list down the data by get method parameters

```
const leanMatrix = await Ct_leantrainingmat.find({
                moduleId: moduleId,
                regionId: regionId,
                "targetgroup.groups": roleId
            });
```

The above query doesn't throw any error, but its empty. i tried to pass values instead of variables, but still it goes empty response. If i remove targetgroup.groups the result for moduleID and regionID works perfectly. Please provide any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one.

```
const leanMatrix = await Ct_leantrainingmat.find({
                moduleId: moduleId,
                regionId: regionId,
                "targetgroup.groups": {$in:[roleId]}
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. i tried but still gets empty response

Comment: i had some issue in collection datas. The array values are not stored in its way. i have corrected it and your support resolves this. thanks